# Git - Wrong folder structure

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

After uploading my project to github, the main content folder looks like that
[image]

I wanted to know if it is possible to change it to [image]

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @JRichardsz IntelliJ

Comment: On eclipse is right click and add to classpath. Git commands does not change folder structure. Just to try, clone some maven git repository and open it.

Comment: Does src/main/resources exist?

Comment: @dan1st yes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why?

You have a directory `java` in a directory `main` in a directory `src`.

`src/main` is just displayed instead of `main` inside `src` because the only directory in `src` is `main` but inside `main`, there are multiple directories (`java` and `resources`). Because of this, GitHub cannot combine `src/main` to `src/main/java`.

In order words, this is just how it is represented in GitHub.

#### How to fix it

If you want GitHub to display `src/main/java`, you would need to remove `src/main/resources` from GitHub (`git rm --cached`, add it to the `.gitignore`, commit and push it) but you may not want this.

Anther option is to create an empty file `.gitkeep` in the `src` directory (and push it). This way, you will have a directory `src` with (that `.gitkeep` file and) a directory `main` with a directory `java` (and `resources`.

But honestly, I would just keep it as it is as this is just a representation of GitHub and most people don't have a problem with that.